# No value in <select> after creating with jQuery

Tags: jquery, select, selected

I´m creating a select element via jQuery and a given array. I can see the options and choose them but there is no active/selected value in the select area, it´s just blank. this is the code i use:

```
output = '';
output += '<select id="testSelect">';
for (var i=0; i<widgetareas.length; i++) {
    output += '<option id="MyId" value="'+widgetareas[i]+'">';
    output += widgetareas[i];       
    output += '</option>';   
}
output += '</select>';

$(target).append(output);
```

I´ve also tried to set a value afterwards like this:

```
$('#testSelect').val("a Value I Know");
```

But nothing works...

Comment: Works fine in Chrome here: http://jsfiddle.net/johnkoer/2XHDJ/4/

Comment: If any of the values in `widgetareas` contains a single quote it will break the formatting.

Comment: Just a note: An `id` shall be unique throughout the document. All your `<option>` tags, however, have the same `id`, namely `MyId`.

Comment: Thanks, than it has to be something different. Have to check the rest of my code again..

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing your following line:

```
output += '>'+widgetareas[i];
```

for this one:

```
output += '&gt;'+widgetareas[i];
```

as the browser would get confused when parsing that end tag inside another tag, so better to use the equivalent entity `&gt;` for the `>` character .

Answer (score 1):

Messing with raw HTML is recipe for a disaster in my opinion.

Another option less prone to problems is creating jQuery objects instead:

```
var ddl = $("<select>").attr("id", "testSelect");
for (var i=0; i<widgetareas.length; i++) {
    ddl.append($("<option>").prop("value", widgetareas[i]).text(widgetareas[i]));
}

$(target).append(ddl);​
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/2XHDJ/8/).

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
output = '';
output += '<select id="testSelect">';
for (var i=0; i<widgetareas.length; i++) {
    output += '<option id="MyId" value="'+widgetareas[i]+'">';
    output +=  widgetareas[i];       
    output += '</option>';   
}
output += '</select>';

$(target).append(output);
```